# Location of PUBG installed on Mac m1 through Steam on Crossover

Tags: steam, pubg-battlegrounds, wine

Let me breakdown my actions:

I installed Crossover on my Macbook m1 air,
then I installed Steam on Crossover,
then I installed PUBG battleground through steam.

Yes, I can see the PUBG icon on my Launchpad, however, when I locate it, it is not showing the entire file (The original size is 33 GIGABYTE).

I want to locate the file downloaded so I can move it to any windows laptop, as crossover can't run it due to some error that's general to M1.

Comment: Even if you could find it, MacOS' executable file (usually .app) and Windows' executable (usually .exe) file is different, so you cannot play it anyway. Just redownload it on Windows.

Comment: I will do that then.